# How to remove parent directories from a filename in a dataframe?

Tags: python, replace, strip

I have created a dataframe which contains 2 columns `"codes"` and `"filename"`. The file names were populated along with the directory path name e.g. `".\XML files\ABC123.xml"`. How do I remove `".\XML files\"` to only leave `"ABC123.xml"`?

I have tried

#1

```
df["filename"] = df["filename"].str.replace(".\XML files\","",regex=False")
```

errors with EOL while scanning string literal

#2

```
df["filename"] = df["filename"].str.replace("".\XML files\"","",regex=False")
```

unexpected character after line continuation character

#3

```
df["filename"] = df["filename"].str.replace(""".\XML files\""","", regex=False")
```

errors with EOL while scanning triple- quoted string literal

#4

```
df["filename"] = df["filename"].str.replace("XML files","", regex=False")
```

this works but leaves me with `".\\ABC123.xml"`

after trying another iteration to remove \

```
df["filename"] = df["filename"].str.replace("\\","", regex=False")
```

I am still left with `".ABC123.xml"`

I am stuck here. how do I remove only the first `"."` and not the second one?

Comment: The problem comes with using a backslash. A simple trick is to use a `raw` string, eg: `replace(r".\XML files", ...`

Comment: Is the quote character before df in each example an accident? It could be responsible for some of your errors

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe? If so, please add the [tag:pandas] tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the \ in the replacement, so for example `df["filename"] = df["filename"].str.replace(".\\XML files","",regex=False")`

Comment: Hi, Thank you, i am still left with a "\ABC123.xml" . i have managed to do it with a second round of clean up for the "\"

Comment: Sure, or you can use .\\XML files\\ as the string being replaced. I think the important part is that \ characters need to be escaped to be replaced :-)